# Best Practice to process multiple rows from database in different thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to ask about the best way to do the following, currently I have many rows that are being inserted into database, with some status like **'NEW'**

One thread(**ThreadA**) is reading 20 rows of the data from table with following query: `select * from TABLE where status = 'NEW' order by some_date asc` and puts read data into the the queue. It only reads data when number of elements in the queue is less then 20.

Another thread(**ThreadB**) is reading data from the queue and processes it, during the process it changes the status of the row to something like **'IN PROGRESS'**.

My fear is that while **ThreadB** is processing one row, but still didn't update its status, if the number of elements in the queue is reduced to be lower than 20, it will fetch another 20 elements and put it into the queue, so there is a possibility of having duplicates in queue.

The data might come back with a status like **'NEW'** I thought that I can update the data read with some flag(something like fetched), and to set the flag as not read after processing.

I feel like I am missing something. So I would like to ask if there some best practice on how to handle tasks similar to this.

PS. Number of threads that read the data might be increased in the future, this is what I try to keep in mind

Comment: There are lots of solutions to this one. In your case, with just one processing thread, you might want for example to store just the records ids in the queue. Then ThreadB can fetch the row itself to make sure the status is indeed NEW. Or use optimistic locking `update table set status='IN_PROGRESS' where id=rowId and status='NEW'` and quit processing this row on exception

Comment: Also might improve a bit by filling the queue when it's say half-empty rather than completely empty

Comment: @pafauk. thanks for the idea of taking only id, I didn't realize it was one of the possible solutions. Currently the queue is not being filled when it is completely empty, on the contrary it is being filled when number of items is lower than 20, which is not a good solution in my opinion as it leads duplicates possibility in the queue

Comment: See another solution I posted as an answer - not much place here in comments for such stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, since no-one seems to be picking this one up, I'll continue here what was started in the comments:

There are lots of solutions to this one. In your case, with just one processing thread, you might want for example to store just the records ids in the queue. Then **ThreadB** can fetch the row itself to make sure the status is indeed `NEW`. Or use optimistic locking with `update table set status='IN_PROGRESS' where id=rowId and status='NEW'` and quit processing this row on exception.

Optimisting locking is fun, and you could also use it to get rid of producer thread altogether. Imagine a few threads, processing records from database. They could each pick up a record, and try to set the status with optimistic locking as in the first example. It's quite possible to get a lot of contention for records this way, so each thread could fetch N rows, where N is number of threads, or twice that much. And then try to process the first row that it succeeded to set `IN_PROGRESS` for. This solution makes for a less complicated system, and one less thing to take care of/synchronize with.

And you can have the thread not only pick up records that are `NEW`, but also these which are `IN_PROGRESS` and `started_date < sysdate = timeout`, that would include records that were not processed because of system failure (like a thread managed to set one row to `IN_PROGRESS` and then your system went down. So you get some resilience here.